# ASP.NET Core 2.0, Kubernetes, https missing in reply address?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, kubernetes-ingress

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application deployed to a Kubernetes cluster. The application is using Azure AD for authentication to some protected pages. The Kubernetes cluster is setup with a Nginx ingress controller and Let's encrypt to support https.

I can access https://x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com with no problem and by clicking on a link on the site I'm directed to https://x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/link, also with no problems.

But, when I click on a link, which requires a logged in user, I get:

```
Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/signin-oidc' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'. More details: not specified
```

Note that URL above misses https and that is the problem.

I have registered "https://x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/signin-oidc" as a reply URL for the application in Azure AD.

But, I don't understand why the reply url used when logging in is missing https.

If I deploy the exact same application to an Azure Web App, I don't get this problem.

What could be the issue?

This is my Ingress YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: x-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # Add to generate certificates for this ingress
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: x-service
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
    # With this configuration kube-lego will generate a secret called `x-tls-secret`
    # for the URL `x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`
    - hosts:
        - "x.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
      secretName: x-tls-secret
```

I have have the following code in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });

    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: You need forwarders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer

Comment: @Tratcher Do you have any more details on how to configure forwarders for this scenario? I have added some of the code referred to in the article you linked to and edited my original post to include that code. But, I still get the same error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x talks about setting the x-forwarded-* headers for nginx. Not show how that maps to kubernetes.

Comment: That is pretty much what I did and I'm using Nginx with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom Middleware in the Configure method to perform the manual http-https redirection

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.IsHttps || context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
    {
        await next();
    }
    else
    {
        string queryString = context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? context.Request.QueryString.Value : string.Empty;
        var https = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + queryString;
        context.Response.Redirect(https);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had a similar problem with ASP .NET Core 3 and the IdentityModel library with a custom OpenID Connect provider. The redirect urls would also be http instead of https.

There were multiple things I had to do to finally get it working:

- configure forward headers to tell ASP .NET Core to use the x-forwared-for and x-forwarded-proto headers the ingress is sending
- tell ASP .NET Core to trust proxies coming from the Kubernetes networks
- raise the forward limit that tells ASP .NET Core how many forwards can happen

Here is the relevant Startup code (be sure to modify the IP ranges according to your cluster:

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
      // This tells the middleware to update IP and scheme according to forwarded headers
      options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
      options.ForwardLimit = 2;

      // Add Kubernetes Networks to trusted networks
      options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("10.42.0.0"), 16));
      options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("the IP range of our cluster nodes"), 27));
    });

    // ...
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
  {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

      // Enable to process forward headers from https proxy like ingress nginx, this middleware must run before others
      // configuration is above in ConfigureServices
      app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    }

    // ...
  }
```

Strangely this would work only sometimes. Sometimes it would still try to redirect to a HTTP page and after a redeploy it would suddenly work. So I also added `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` to the `Configure` method and it finally seems to work every time.

Edit: A little down in [this blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/17/hosting-asp-net-core-behind-https-in-google-kubernetes-engine/) it's explained on why you need to set the ForwardLimit at least to 2.